# How to get the first n items from a sorted dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a sorted dictionary with word and frequencies:

```
words = {'dog':8, 'cat':7, 'pig':4 ......}
```

Is there an elegant way to pick the first 3 items? So that it ends up with:

```
words = {'dog':8, 'cat':7, 'pig':4}
```

I can set a threshold k = 3 and do a for loop, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How do you have sorted dictionary?

Comment: Python does not have any type of object called sorted dictionary. Is this something you implemented or are you saying that you want the first 3 items of a dictionary after sorting it?

Comment: I sorted it by myself, so it's a sorted OrderedDict.

Comment: Maybe sort list of keys and just `for k in keys[:3]:`?

Comment: @Denis, the OP said they want a better way to do it other than a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are using Python 3.6 or less:**

You can't use a regular python dictionary for this as these are never sorted. Use the `collections` and `OrderedDict` class to store your dictionary if you want a sorted dictionary.

```
words = OrderedDict(list(words.items())[:n])
```

**If you are using Python 3.7+**

You can use this code (without using `itertools`):

```
words = dict(list(words.items())[:n])
```

Comment: The first 3 items would be `[:3]`.

Comment: I have: `d = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}`, use `dict(list(d.items())[:2])` and get: `{'a': 1, 'c': 3}` — am I doing something wrong

Comment: No, you aren't. This is the intended result! This code is supposed to get the first two elements from the dictionary, and that is what is happening here. What were you expecting as the output?

Answer (score 5):

Since the word frequencies are integers, you can use the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method on a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You can even use the `Counter` to conveniently get the frequencies in the first place:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sentence = 'the black cat sat on the black mat on the floor'
>>> freqs = Counter(sentence.split())
>>> freqs.most_common(3)
[('the', 3), ('black', 2), ('on', 2)]
```

It returns a list of pairs, so if you want the result as a dictionary, you can use the `dict` constructor:

```py
>>> dict(freqs.most_common(3))
{'the': 3, 'black': 2, 'on': 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this code.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> words = {'dog':8, 'cat':7, 'pig':4, 'rabbit': 3}
>>> dict(islice(words.items(), 3))
{'dog': 8, 'cat': 7, 'pig': 4}
```

Comment: This only works Python 3.6+ (as this is when python dicts were ordered)

Comment: It works in any version of Python if `words` is an OrderedDict in the right order, as in the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

It's still technically a for loop but perhaps more elegant?

```
{x:words[x] for x in list(words)[0:3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Requires Python 3.6+:

```
>>> k = 3
>>> words = {'dog':8, 'cat':7, 'pig':4, 'cow':8}
>>> dict([z for i,z in enumerate(words.items()) if i<k])
{'dog': 8, 'cat': 7, 'pig': 4}
```

Explanation: the `.items()` method returns key-value pairs as tuples, so you get a list of tuples back when you do the list comprehension `[z for i,z in enumerate(words.items()) if i<k]` by itself. Conveniently, the `dict()` constructor accepts a list of key-value tuples, and will put them all into a new dict. So passing the list comprehension into `dict()` returns the desired dictionary.

Comment: This doesn't even give the correct answer.

Comment: check your Python version. this depends on dictionaries being ordered, which is only the default in Python 3.6+.

Comment: I didn't test but based on you input and output, it is clear that it is not giving the right answer. `cow` is 8, but it is not in the output list. I guess you assume the dictionary is sorted.

Comment: Um... that's the point, @smttsp. We want to only keep the _first three_ elements - meaning this is a valid answer.